# Doing something after elapsed time C++ SFML 2

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sfml, visual-c++-2010

I have a clock and timer in SFML and it measures seconds. I'm trying to make the next action happen after a certain amount of seconds elapsed ( specifically 4) Here's my code

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include "SplashScreen1.h"

using namespace std;

void SplashScreen1::show(sf::RenderWindow & renderWindow)
{
    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time elapsed = clock.getElapsedTime();

    sf::Texture splash1;
    sf::SoundBuffer buffer;
    sf::Sound sound;

    if(!buffer.loadFromFile("sounds/splah1.wav"))
    {
        cout << "Articx-ER-1C: Could not find sound splah1.wav" << endl;
    }

    sound.setBuffer(buffer);

    if(!splash1.loadFromFile("textures/splash1.png"))
    {
        cout << "Articx-ER-1C: Could not find texture splash1.png" << endl;
    }

    sf::Sprite splashSprite1(splash1);

    sound.play();
    renderWindow.draw(splashSprite1);
    renderWindow.display();

    sf::Event event;

    while(true)
    {
        while(renderWindow.pollEvent(event))
        {
            //if(event.type == sf::Event::EventType::KeyPressed
            if(elapsed.asSeconds() >= 4.0f)
            {
                //|| event.type == sf::Event::EventType::MouseButtonPressed)
                //|| event.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed
                return;
            }

            if(event.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed)
                renderWindow.close();
        }
    }
}
```

It does nothing after 4 seconds. I believe I'm gathering the elapsed time incorrectly. I know my return is working because I tried it with mouse input and it worked fine.

Comment: Are you sure, that you want EXACTLY 4 seconds? Not just when 4 seconds have past?

Comment: Well, I want the return value to occur aft 4 seconds, I'm not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: Well the code you have now, will only get run if EXACTLY 4 seconds have passed at the if statement (and if the binary representation of that is the exact same as the one in the if statement (the same number can and will have different binary representation in floats)), not if 3.9999 or 4.00001 seconds have past, so what I think you want is >=4.0 seconds

Comment: Yeah, I really don't care if it's not exactly 4 seconds and I did try >= 4.0f and it didn't work.

Comment: In that case, theres more than one issue with the code, thats for sure.

Comment: Well my code for the clock and time was just 
 sf::Clock clock;
 sf::Time elapsed = clock.getElapsedTime();

Comment: And your sure that reset isnt called more frequently than 4 seconds?

Comment: I haven't called reset.

Comment: I added the rest of the code above.

Comment: I sound the issue and posted the fix as an answer below, you were not updating your time variable as you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine now, except that you should update your elapsed variable inside the loop (read it from your clock).

Currently your just reading it once, and comparing that static value to 4 a lot of times.

The time type represents a point in time, and is hence static.

Your code should be;

```
...
while(renderWindow.pollEvent(event)) 
{
    elapsed = clock.getElapsedTime(); 
    // Rest of the loop code
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Floating-point comparisons cannot be made so exactly.  `== 4.0f` can almost never be true.  Try `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the SFML timer to work for some reason, you can consider doing it using ctime (time.h).

```
#include <ctime>
/* ... */
time_t beginT = time(NULL), endT = time(NULL);
while(renderWindow.pollEvent(event)) {

  if(difftime(endT, beginT) < 4.0f) {
    endT = time(NULL);
  }
  else {
    beginT = time(NULL);
    endT = time(NULL)

    /* do the after-4-seconds-thingy */
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

Briefly explained, you set endT to the current time until it differs a full 4 seconds from the previously set beginT.

Comment: Using Ctime is also a fine solution